# in AsyncTask"can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask for receiving data from the database, here is my full code:

> line26

```
 public class Tabasync2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    static Posdent tempposdent;
    ...
    ArrayList<Posdent> aResults = new ArrayList<Posdent>();

public static Posdent send() {
    return tempposdent;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
  ...}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sText) {
   ...
   ...
        Posdent P = getList(result);
   ...
    return result;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String v) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
   Tabs t=new Tabs();
```

> line:99

```
    t.calling(aResults);
}

public Posdent getList(String name) {
    tempposdent = new Posdent();
    String name1 = null;
    try {
        JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);

        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < Jarray.length(); k++) {
            try {
                JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
                Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(k);
                String msg = Jasonobject.getString("message");

                name1 = Jasonobject.getString("s_name");
                Tabs t1=new Tabs();
                t1.testing(name1);
                tempposdent = new Posdent();

                tempposdent.setStudent_name(name1);
                tempposdent.setMessage(msg);
                for(int j=0;j<aResults.size();j++)
                {
                    if(aResults.get(j).hashCode()!=(tempposdent.hashCode())){
                        aResults.add(tempposdent);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException js) {
                js.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());

    }
    Tabs t=new Tabs();

    t.testing(name1);
    return tempposdent;
}
}
```

this is my new logcat trace:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211)
        at com.student.anurag.student_connect.Tabs$SearchResultAdapter.<init>(Tabs.java:144)
        at com.student.anurag.student_connect.Tabs.calling(Tabs.java:115)
        at com.student.anurag.student_connect.Tabasync2.onPostExecute(Tabasync2.java:99)
        at com.student.anurag.student_connect.Tabasync2.onPostExecute(Tabasync2.java:26)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also i would like to include that from the main activity when i m pressing a button two things are happening:

- first AsyncTask posts data
- other AsyncTask retrieves data;
  like this:

  ```
  switch(v.getId()) {

         case R.id.postb:

         new task1().execute();

         new Tabasync2().execute(ep.getText().toString());

         break;

         }
  ```

here is the tabs class snippet:

> line 115

```
public void calling(ArrayList<Posdent> aResults) {
    searchResults.setAdapter(new SearchResultAdapter(context, aResults));
}

 class SearchResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int count;
    Typeface type;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<Posdent> sdetails = new ArrayList<Posdent>();

    public SearchResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Posdent> aResults) {
```

> line 144

```
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        this.sdetails = aResults;
        this.count = aResults.size();
        this.context = context;
        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/book.TTF");
        Log.d("Inside SearchResultAdapter", "" + count);
    }
```

Comment: show full code of class in which extending AsyncTask

Comment: `Posdent P = getList(result);` remove this line from `doInBackground` and add it in `onPostExecute`. it will work

Comment: Show much more of the logcat. It will exactly tell you which is the offending code line.

Comment: Are both asynctasks independent? Or does the second one use the posted data of the first one? If so your code is wrong.

Comment: @ScionofIkshvaku  thanks as the error went..but can you tell me if the code fo rretreiving is correct or not..because i cannot obtain the data, if not how can i do it

Comment: `doInBackground` returns a `String`, but the parameter of `onPostExecute` is `Void`, are you kidding me? Can your codes be compiled?

Comment: @SilentKnight thanks, I made the change. But now another error has come I hope you can surely help, thank you. I have editted the code above and added the new log trace..please help

Comment: can anyone help please.